# Prove the polynomials (1-t)... generate the polynomials space 3 degree

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

> Prove the polynomials $\left(1-t\right)^{3},\,\left(1-t\right)^{2},\,1-t,\,1$ generate the $\mathsf{P\mathrm{_{3}\left(t\right)}}$ space of polynomials of degree $\leq3$ .

I work this problem as follow:

$\alpha_{1}\left(1-t\right)^{3}+\alpha_{2}\left(1-t\right)^{2}+\alpha_3\left(1-t\right)+\alpha_4\left(1\right)=a\,+bt\,+ct^{2}\,+dt^{3}$

\begin{cases}
\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}+\alpha_{3}+\alpha_{4}=a\\
-3\alpha_{1}-2\alpha_{2}-\alpha_{3}=b\\
3\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}=c\\
\alpha_{1}=d
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
\alpha_{1}=d\\
\alpha_{2}=c-3d\\
\alpha_{3}=-2c+3d-b\\
\alpha_{4}=-d+c+b+a
\end{cases}

and then the vector generate the space.

And now, my question.
Am I working fine in this problem?? because i'm not sure.

Comment: Since $\;\dim P_3[t]=4\;$ you could also prove those 4 polynomials are linearly independent.

Comment: Yep, thank man.